# css bootsrap , align buttons in the div container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

so here's the problem 
i want to align my buttons , in the div
here the result 
[my view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jhhq5.png)

i've tried some css but it dont work
now i am not using any custom css for this div

here's my blade file

```
 <td>
                          <div class="container">


                            <form method="POST" action="{{ route('users.destroy',$user->id) }}">
                              {{ csrf_field() }}
                              {{ method_field('delete') }}


                                  {{-- <!––  //With the <a> tag you are sending a get request.
                                  that's why we changed it like that because the destroy method require a DELETE request
                                  thank you stackoverflow you saved me  ––> --}}
                              <button type="submit"   class="btn btn-danger" ><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                              </button> 
                            </form>
                           <a href="{{ route('users.show',$user->id) }}"><button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
                            <a href="{{ route('users.edit',$user->id) }}"> <button  type="button" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>

                            </div>
                          </td>
```

Comment: Can you create a reproducible snippet? it looks like half cooked code and may not be able to help you correctly. both HTML and CSS code is needed.

Comment: I am not certain you can align buttons from the OUTSIDE of a form with the buttons from INSIDE the form, not without introducing more columns and rows in tables/divs.

Comment: @Manjuboyz i didnt get you , i am new here

Comment: @KaseyChang how tried it but it dont work

Comment: You'll have to show some code to demonstrate WHAT did not work for you.

Comment: Sounds like those two other buttons need to go to a separate TD. What is that DIV container doing there anyway?

Comment: Try to move the two other buttons inside the `form`. I'm pretty sure it'll work. Just a sidenote, you have forgot to close your `a` tags in the last two buttons

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-nowrap` class to the form, and they will be in one line.